# Android Studio download music youtube video

Tags: android, youtube, download-manager

I try to make a youtube video downloader, I use android-youtubeExtractor from https://jitpack.io, it's work with all video except music and video who can't be display in embded like : https://www.youtube.com/embed/q2c7Ie1Sz1Q.
That's my code :

```
public void downloadVideo(View v){
    String link = webView.getUrl();
    YouTubeUriExtractor youTubeUriExtractor = new YouTubeUriExtractor(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onUrisAvailable(String videoId, String videoTitle, SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles) {
            if(ytFiles != null){
                int tag = 22;
                String title = "test";
                newLink = ytFiles.get(tag).getUrl();
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(newLink));
                request.setTitle(title);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,title+".mp4");
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);

                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
        }
    };
    youTubeUriExtractor.execute(link);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/issues/99

Comment: It's still doesn't work

Comment: by the way what is the error in logcat?

Comment: is aything showing?

Comment: The app just do nothing

Comment: https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/issues/147 ok that's 'normal'